# MongoDB issue with mongoose

Tags: mongodb

This is the message i am getting when i tries to run my new app any one who can fix this issue

```
^
```

Error: Cannot find module 'mongodb/node_modules/bson'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:326:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:277:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object. (C:\wamp\www\NodeExpress\beautiBlog\node_mo
ss-sessions\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\obj
16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:398:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:405:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
 [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
npm install -g node-gyp 
cd /to/your/project-folder
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
```

Source: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/2718

Comment: i did this but no luck